# Chartkick Gem "couldn't find file 'chartkick' with type 'application/javascript'" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I use rails 5.1.6 and in the website https://chartkick.com/, it tells the user how to download and use chartkick. So I bundle installed the gem "chartkick", then because I use rails 5.1.6, in app/assets/javascripts/application.js, I added //= require chartkick
//= require Chart.bundle.

Gemfile.lock

`chartkick (3.2.1)`

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require chartkick
//= require Chart.bundle
```

When I ran it, I got a error

couldn't find file 'chartkick' with type 'application/javascript'//= require chartkick //= require Chart.bundle

and it highlights that they was a error in this line //= require chartkick

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. To solve the problem I used git reset to go back to my last commit. I then opened up my gemfile, add `gem 'chartkick'` and then ran `bundle install` and it worked this time. I hope this might help you even though it sounds simple. I don't know what I did to get into the original mess.